# Swift Uikit navigate to starting view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an `Ios` app build with `Swift` `UIKit`,
where all views are embedded in a bottom navigation within the soryboard.
I want to navigate to the home view (starting view) from another view on a button click programmatically, so not presenting it above the current view or pushing it ontop, so that a "back" button won't appear,
same as if a user would just load the app for the first time,

How can I accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, put this code in your tap action func:

```
let controller = YourStartController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if do you want to replace navigation controller animation :

```
let controller = YourStartController()
let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    guard let window = view.window else { return }
    window.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    
    present(YourStartController, animated: false, completion: nil) // important, set animated to false
```

**EDIT**

This is an example for transition:

My first Controller:

```
class FirstController: UIViewController {

let goToSecondButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.backgroundColor = .red
    b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    b.setTitle("Go to second", for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSecondController), for: .touchUpInside)
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return b
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    view.addSubview(goToSecondButton)
    goToSecondButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    goToSecondButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    goToSecondButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    goToSecondButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    
}

@objc fileprivate func goToSecondController() {
    let controller = SecondController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
    guard let window = view.window else { return }
    window.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    
    present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil) // important, set animated to false
 }
}
```

My second Controller:

```
class SecondController: UIViewController {

let backToFirst: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.backgroundColor = .white
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.setTitle("Back To first", for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backToFirstController), for: .touchUpInside)
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return b
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(backToFirst)
    backToFirst.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    backToFirst.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    backToFirst.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    backToFirst.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    
}

@objc fileprivate func backToFirstController() {
    let controller = FirstController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    guard let window = view.window else { return }
    window.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    
    present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil) // important, set animated to false
 }
}
```

This is the result

[image]

This is an example without transition:

My first controller:

```
class FirstController: UIViewController {

let goToSecondButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.backgroundColor = .red
    b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    b.setTitle("Go to second", for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSecondController), for: .touchUpInside)
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return b
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    view.addSubview(goToSecondButton)
    goToSecondButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    goToSecondButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    goToSecondButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    goToSecondButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    
}

@objc fileprivate func goToSecondController() {
    let controller = SecondController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

My Second Controller:

```
class SecondController: UIViewController {

let backToFirst: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.backgroundColor = .white
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.setTitle("Back To first", for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backToFirstController), for: .touchUpInside)
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return b
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(backToFirst)
    backToFirst.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    backToFirst.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    backToFirst.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    backToFirst.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    
}

@objc fileprivate func backToFirstController() {
    let controller = FirstController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! using the first snippet it seems like the navigation works but i'm getting the following error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" after navigating to the starting view, when setting the text on a Label to a localized string (using NSLocalizedString) in viewWillAppear, do you maybe know what am i doing wrong? sorry am pretty new to swift/ios

Comment: @Blueprint I update my answer with two examples for help you to understand well... If it's OK, sign for right answer and upvote... Thanks